# How to Export/Transfer DHCP data?

Tags: windows, dhcp, migration

We have a very old server HP ML110. It is beginning to cause hardware (power) troubles. We are hosting DHCP services on this on Windows Server 2000.

Now I would like to transfer all the DHCP data (it has reserved IP addresses) from this old server to a new server which is Windows Server 2003.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325473) Microsoft KB article should help